# PHP jquery random change div background for each season

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i have 10 background for each season (Spring-summer ...) in folder (1, 2 , 3 ,4). Now I need to random change div background for each season. i mean for spring change random image of folder 1.

how do can change background using PHP Or mixed jquery/css?!

Comment: Do you want to randomly change the background during a single page visit or just a random image on each page reload?

Comment: Can you share your code? What ideas you have come up with so far?

Comment: @Paul: a single page visit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a random image on each page reload, include the following snippet in your PHP template file.

```
$season = 'spring';
function random_pic($season)
{
    $dir = 'backgrounds/' . $season;
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
```

To get the `$season` value dynamically, you can refer to [Jerodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743016/jerodev)'s [answer](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Season.html) to do that and include that function as well.

Comment: Possibly limit the folder scan to image files only :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own code to detect season in php. There is no existing function that will return the current season. The problem is that this is different for the northern and the southern hemisphere.

[This](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Season.html) page has a very nice example on how to get the current season. Once you have that, you can use a switch statement to select the folder where a background should be selected.

Next, you can use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to find all files in this folder and use [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) to select one of those files.

The last part is to put the image in your html. The easiest way to do this is using inline css, but you could also pass the path to a jQuery script and let that handle the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to current day and track if it is in which season , So based on this , fetch files from server as per season to apply theme .You wll do it in php / cakephp better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Get Season, have a predermined number of images in each folder and named in the following manner: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg:

```
//Get Season
$month = DATE("m");
$season = "winter";

if ($month >= "03" && $month <= "05")
  $season = "spring";
elseif($month >="06" && $month <="08")
  $season = "summer";
elseif ($month >= "09" && $month <= "11")
  $season = "autumn";

//Generate a random number between 1 and 10 (change to match your range of backgrounds)
$random_number = rand (1, 10);

$image_path = "backgrounds/" . $season . "/" . $random_number . ".jpg";

// Print into tag, CSS code, etc
echo "Image path: " . $image_path;
```